# SpringBoard quit unexpectedly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, nsnotificationcenter

Can anyone help me with the following problem please ? Every time when I try touch and swipe down the notification. I get following error and iOS simulators restarts. I tried reinstall Xcode and It didn`t help. I tried different version of simulators. From iphone 6 to iphone 8

```
Process:               SpringBoard [5139]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
Identifier:            SpringBoard
Version:               1.0 (50)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [4875]
Responsible:           SpringBoard [5139]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-10-28 08:09:15.159 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13 (17A405)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        CF9C10C7-F4C9-1CC8-7D45-E336797E531B

Sleep/Wake UUID:       CE87E042-97E5-49EF-8466-B49FDB0354A9

Time Awake Since Boot: 47000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       630 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to receive a participant from the arbiter'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
CoreSimulator 494.22.3 - Device: iPhone 8 - Runtime: iOS 11.0 (15A8401) - DeviceType: iPhone 8
```

Here is my viewController code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // 1. REQUEST PERMISSION
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            if granted {
                print("Notification access granted")
            } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            }
        }

    }

    @IBAction func notoify(_ sender: UIButton) {
        scheduleNotification(inSeconds: 5, completion: {
            success in if success {
                print("Ok")
            } else {
                print("Error scheduled notification")
            }

        })
    }

    func scheduleNotification(inSeconds: TimeInterval, completion: @escaping (_ Success: Bool) -> ()){

        let notification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        notification.title =  "Notification"
        notification.subtitle =  "These are great"
        notification.body = "Test test test test test test test test"

        let notificationTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: inSeconds, repeats: false)

        let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "myNotification", content: notification, trigger: notificationTrigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationRequest, withCompletionHandler: {
            error in if error != nil {
                print(error as Any)
                completion(false)
            }
            else {
                completion(true)
            }
        })

    }

}
```

Comment: cd Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData,  remove whole files and then restart Xcode.

Comment: It didn't help :(

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently after I updated my xcode to version 11.4.1. The only I got this issue fixed to uninstall xcode completely and reinstall it. Once the reinstallation is done I did not see this error any more and all my Flutter and other mobile projects worked without any more issues.

Answer (score 0):

After experiencing the exact same issue, uninstalling XCode completely and re-installing worked for me as well.